# Error: No such file or directory

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the command rosrun svmlight extract_pc_features. Here svmlight is a user defined package which is in the ros environment path. I am getting the following error once I run the command.

```
/opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rosrun: line 73: /home/shahriar/ucfWorkspace/svmlight/bin/extract_pc_features: No such file or directory
```

But my extract_pc_features in in that location.

```
shahriar@iqbal:~/ucfWorkspace/svmlight/bin$ ls
background_subtraction  calc_intersection    filterRect
baseline                centroid_grasp       rank
boost_training          extract_pc_features  showRect
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119251/error:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [Iqbal 1988](https://answers.ros.org/users/10966/iqbal-1988/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Occasionally, you'll see a 'file not found' error if the interpreter that's supposed to run a particular executable can't be found.

This can happen if you have a `#!` at the beginning of your file that is either misspelled, or references an interpreter that doesn't exit.

It can also happen if you're trying to execute a non-native binary, and the kernel can't find an appropriate interpreter. I've usually seen this when trying to run i386 or ARM binaries on x86_64.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Iqbal 1988](https://answers.ros.org/users/10966/iqbal-1988/) on 2014-01-18**:
Thank you for your answer.

I got over the previous problem..
Now I am getting this error...
/home/shahriar/ucfWorkspace/svmlight/bin/extract_pc_features: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.2.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-19**:
If you've solved this problem, you should indicate how you solved it, to help others who have the same problem. Your missing library error sounds like a new problem, and you should ask it as a new question.